# Recommendation to treat multiple language sites

Tags: php, html, css, performance

Gente, How do you recommend to treat multiple language sites?

Im been working like this:

1 - Having all text/imgpath in variables (lang/es.php, lang/en.php).

2 - Keeping files separated taking into account similarities.

```
/
css/
es/
en/
images/
```

3 - with CMS (wordpres)

Now the issue is that not always work with CMS as the aforementioned. Most cases are handmade.

I had commented on working with XML, but ultimately I think it is about the same as what brought the xml should be dumped to a variable, keep the id of the language within a session (or whatever form).

I think has to be a better way to do this.

As an example I put a case:

```
Screenshoot =  https://i.stack.imgur.com/yOQM5.jpg
```

Hope you could  help me :D.

THanks

Answer (score 2):

The solution depends on the need. I have implemented complex translation utilities for massive multi-language sites as well as very basic english/spanish solutions for much smaller ones.

The larger ones were database driven on the back end, but static on the front. We load in the proper file for the language based on the user's session. Since massive queries were undesirable, we wrote the html of the translated content into flat text files and called them like so:

```
<?php 
if(file_exists($_SESSION['lang'].'/path-to-file.html'))
{
    include($_SESSION['lang'].'/path-to-file.html');
}  
else
{
  //call some helper to fetch it on the fly
}
?>
```

However, not all sites demand a huge database driven language utility. You might have a basic site that could easily be handled by a simple config file:

```
$lang = [
    'en' => [
        'title' => 'the title in english',
        'header_1' => 'header 1 in english'
    ],
    'sp' => [
        'title' => 'the title in spanish',
        'header_1' => 'header 1 in spanish'
    ]
];
```

where you would include the file that has this var on every page and then call the language strings as needed:

```
<h1><?php echo $lang['en']['title']; ?></h1>
```

If you need a better example of what might work for you, you should modify your question to include the expected size of your translations and how the languages may affect the layout and design of your site.

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested by [gettext](http://php.net/manual/en/book.gettext.php).

It takes care of plural and it's very easy to use.
Some languages could be very hard to manage using arrays or static files.

Comment: `gettext` is OK for small pieces of text, but not for whole sites.

Comment: the difficulty naturally lies in the scope of the site more than the language itself. Since both methods I suggested required a user to translate manually, plurals should not be a problem. An important thing to consider in any case is making sure your site knows how to handle multibyte characters if necessary. You don't want to use substr() or some such function and have it split in the middle of a multibyte character.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend looking into the internationalization features that come with PHP.

See the manual here http://php.net/manual/en/book.intl.php